# TFS REST upload attachment permission problems

Tags: python, rest, tfs, permissions

I'm implementing TFS to our service. I'm using OAuth2, and it is working like a charm. I'm requesting permission scopes "**vso.work_write vso.project**" but somehow I'm not able to upload attachments. I'm getting 403 Forbidden from the server. As MS documentation is full of holes on this subject can maybe somebody point out **if my scope permission are OK or not? Which should I add to my auth**?

It is probably not important but I'm using Nginx/Python, and making requests with the standard Request lib.

Code example:

```
def __auth(self):
        return "Bearer " + self.token  

def __makeUrl(self, resource, project=None):
        if project:
            return (self.baseurl % (self.domain, "%s/" % project)) + resource
        else:
            return (self.baseurl % (self.domain, "")) + resource
```

*code that will make request:*

```
headers={'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Authorization': self.__auth()}

url = self.__makeUrl(("/wit/attachments?fileName=%s&api-version=1.0" % fileName), self.project)
response = self.client.post(url, base64.b64encode(filecontent), headers=headers)
```

Heads up for the code. I'm almost sure that generate URL is OK as I'm using the same logic for other requests (e.q. project and project type read)

I could really use a push to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.... This one is painful, but **it looks like I do not need project name in the URL when uploading attachments**. That was the mistake. Scope permissions are fine. (at the moment I'm testing with everything enabled) but I will post my final status if something will be different.

Too bad service is not providing a little bit more useful information for debugging.

So, if anyone have similar problems make sure you double check you URL as it is not in constant format thru all requests.

**Also make sure that /wit/attachments?filename is in small letters**. As in documentation you can find it in both formats.

**And it looks like that I have to upload pictures without base64 encoding**. That is done automatically from S3 bucket library I'm using to read the image content data.